# Purpose of Objects.isNull(...) / Objects.nonNull(...)

Tags: java

What is the purpose of

```
Objects.isNull(x)
```

if we can simply write

```
x == null
```

?

Same for

```
Objects.nonNull(...)
```

and

```
x != null
```

Comment: I do not know but I guess OOP or Not OOP this is a question?

Comment: I don't know too, but the API Note may explain something: `This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

From [the JavaDoc of the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-):

> API Note:
>       This method exists to be used as a `Predicate`, `filter(Objects::isNull)`

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating the above answer further with an example. Given a list of strings, `Objects.isNull` and `Objects.nonNull` can be used to filter out the `null` and `non null` values respectively from the list.

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("T", null, "S");

// Filter out all the elements that are not null.    
stringList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()); // "T","S"

// Filter out all the null elements.
stringList.stream().filter(Objects::isNull).collect(Collectors.toList()); // null
```