# Replace this lambda with method reference 'Objects::nonNull'

Tags: java-8

I have written code to find the latest date from a list of an object that contains Date variable.

`list.stream().map(segment -> segment.lastLoad).filter(x->x!=null).max(Date::compareTo).get()`

But I am getting sonar issue stating

> Replace this lambda with method reference 'Objects::nonNull'.

What I am not able to figure out is where can I use Method reference stated by sonar lint issue.

Comment: `.filter(x->x!=null)`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140193/purpose-of-objects-isnull-objects-nonnull

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.filter(x->x!=null) == .filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

It's interesting that you already use a method reference in(but failed to see this one):

```
max(Date::compareTo)
```

Also you are obviously returning a `Date` but from an `Optional<Date>`, you should get a warning (if using IDEA) that it's not safe to call `get` directly on an `Optional`.

And you could also replace that `max(Date::compareTo)` with `max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` since `Date` is already `Comparable`.

Comment: first, up-vote. I add some shortcut here, if you using IDEA, put your cursor in highlighted part, and then press `ALT+ENTER`, you then can see optimization options.

Comment: I had no idea about `Objects` class. Thanks to you now I know.

Comment: …and I recommend replacing `max(Date::compareTo)` with `max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.