# How to replace "!= null" statement with method reference?

Tags: java, methods, lambda, reference

My Intelij shows me that I can replace the lambda `.filter(bean -> bean != null)` with a method reference. Its is obviuos for me how to do it when I have a Class or an Object with methods. But how to do a reference on `!= null`, is there a Class that has some kind of `isNull()` method?

Comment: Why can't you just have intellij show you what it suggests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of Objects.isNull(…) / Objects.nonNull(…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140193/purpose-of-objects-isnull-objects-nonnull)

Comment: sure, the reason is because this post is not asking about the purpose of `isNull` or `nonNull`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the exact reason why the [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) API exists:

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course; you can use the `Objects::nonNull` API.

```
package com.logicbig.example.objects;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NonNullExample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(null, null, "first_element", "second_element", null);
        list = list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from comment to answer*

Of course, as Aomine says, you can use `Objects::nonNull` for this.

But for code that doesn't have an available function, I think it's useful to know that you can use a lot of things in lambda expressions; You can use code blocks or just write a simple method following the contract of the lambda and passing a reference to that method.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stream<Object> stream = ...;

        // lambda from code block
        stream.filter(bean -> {return bean != null;});

        Predicate<Object> p1 = o ->  {return o != null;};

        // which resolves to the below
        Predicate<Object> p2 = new Predicate<>() {
            @Override public boolean test(Object o) {
                return o != null;
            }
        };

        // or pass your own method that can resolve to the correct functional class
        stream.filter(Test::myPredicateTest);
    }

    // meets the contract of a Predicate<Object>.test(Object o) returning boolean
    public static boolean myPredicateTest(Object o) {
        return o != null;
    }
}
```